# chromedriver.exe stopped working popup is appearing on windows machine when login to gdrive

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**Chrome Driver:2.37.544315

Chrome Browser version: 65.0.3297.0

Selenium version : 3.11.0**

Description: Browser is getting launched , It is opening gdrive login page. After entering username , password when we are clicking next . we are getting below failure logs.

Logs:

Getting below exception in Google and login getting failed
2018-07-11 10:28:53 [ERROR] java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46086
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'M275982K9HV2L', ip: '172.16.221.98', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46086

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpIGi.png)

Comment: Are you using remotewebdriver or local webdriver ? Please add a code snippet.

Comment: Updated Chrome Driver to latest driver and it got resolved thanks